# Is it safe to delete files in /root?

Tags: 14.04

Because I was unable to install an update on my ubuntu 14.04 system I found out that it was caused by running out of inodes, so I got the 'disk full' error.
Searching for the cause gave me 2 enormous folders:
`/root/Y47IfC0A11` and `/root/0otOGsADcy`.

What are those files/folders used for and can I remove without risk?
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What's in them?

Comment: How can I see that? Gedit?

Comment: No @frie do not use anything else but command line tools. Do no execute anything in these directories. Use `more {filename}`  to see content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not really be possible for us to answer what these are but if **you** do not know what these are... `/root/` should only hold hidden directories and files and anything installed there should be considered suspicious.

Contents of mine ...

```
ls -la /root
total 24
drwx------  4 root root 4096 okt  7 22:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 nov 12 03:46 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 okt 22  2015 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 okt  7 09:43 .cache
drwx------  3 root root 4096 okt  7 22:29 .gnupg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 aug 17  2015 .profile
```

You really should know what these are: try to remember what you installed. If you do can not remember where this is from the worst case scenario: your system got compromised.

Examine the files in the directories using the commands `more` and `file` and see if you can find hints on what these are. Then delete the directories and set a new password for your admin account.
Also consider reinstalling your system.

Comment: I have tried to find out what the contents of the files were, but without result. The only thing I could tell that it were 2 directories with millions(!) of small files. It took the processor (old Dell desktop) more than 3 hours to remove the files, but after that the free disk space increased with more than 15GB and my used inodes decreased from 100% to 34%. Most important: everything runs perfect now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`/root` is typically the home directory of the `root` user. With a sane system configuration it's unlikely that you'll break anything crucial for Ubuntu by deleting some of all of its content (though you might make some things harder).

These folders may be left-over temporary directories from some application running as `root` or it may be from a malware that tries to obfuscate its presence by installing itself inside directories with cryptic names (see Rinzwind's answer).